# Convert LOWORD(wParam) to const wchar_t*

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I develop calculator app as a homework and and I check which digit is pressed like this:

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) == buttonDigit0) {
    writeToOperand(L"0");
}
else if (LOWORD(wParam) == buttonDigit1) {
    writeToOperand(L"1");
}
else if (LOWORD(wParam) == buttonDigit2) {
    writeToOperand(L"2");
}
// ...
```

Where `writeToOperand` is `void writeToOperand(const wchar_t* digit);`

And I want to minify it like this:

```
if (LOWORD(wParam) >= 100 && LOWORD(wParam) <= 109) {
   writeToOperand(LOWORD(wParam));
}
```

Where `100` is id of button `#define buttonDigit0 100` and `109` is `#define buttonDigit9 109`.
But I don't follow how can I convert `LOWORD(wParam)` to `const wchar_t*` for my `writeToOperand` function.

Comment: LOWORD is the lower 16 bits, how can this be a 32/64-bit address? It should be converting a value to string

Comment: @JonathanPotter thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use a local `wchar_t` array variable to store the computed digit:

```
wchar_t digit[2] = {0}; // reserve place for terminating null...
if (LOWORD(wParam) >= 100 && LOWORD(wParam) <= 109) {
   digit[0] = static_cast<wchar_t>('0' + LOWORD(wParam) - 100); // explicit cast to avoid a warning
   writeToOperand(digit);
}
```

But you must compute the actual value and store it into a local array to be able to pass the address to `writeToOperand`

Comment: Thank you so much!